# I need to execute the function only for n times and then stop

Tags: java, android

In the below code, I want the take picture to execute for n times and then stop.

I tried using the for loop but I get the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal`.

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");

            startBackgroundThread();
            if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
                openCamera();
            } else {
                textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
            }


            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    takePicture();


                }


            }, 200, 15000);


    }
```

Comment: That means you don't release the camera resource completely in method takePicture(). And that results in failing to use camera again.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `takePicture`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a count of taken pictures and then just cancel the Timer like:

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");

            startBackgroundThread();
            if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
                openCamera();
            } else {
                textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
            }

            final int PICTURES_LIMIT = 10;

            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                int pictureNo = 0;
                public void run() {                
                    takePicture();
                    pictureNo++;
                    if (pictureNo>PICTURES_LIMIT) {
                       timer.cancel();
                    }

                }


            }, 200, 15000);


    }
```

Comment: My first problem is solved, know my application only takes pictures for n times but after n i still get camera preview i want to stop camera preview and enter new activity.

Comment: @AbhilashK For these things, search for answres and ask another question in case you would not found one.